# How to get Pressure from a Tablet PC to be used with HTML5-Canvas

Tags: html5-canvas, tablet-pc, pressure

I want to draw with my Tablet PC (HP Elitebook) in a web page, and I want to create a "Paint" that I can use in a web browser, using HTML5-Canvas if possible.

I'm new to Tablet PC programming ... and I only found ways to manage stylus pressure with a Microsoft library or QT ... but it is not for webpages.
I also found that there is something for Wacom tablets ( http://www.wacomeng.com/web/index.html ) but it doesn't seems to work with my Tablet PC.

So how can I manage Tablet inputs in a website (and especialy get pressure) ?
And also, what are the most commun and well documented library (in C/C++/Java) for managing a Tablet PC ?

Comment: Wow, you read my mind on asking that question. I don't know if it's possible for a web page to get at that data, I really hope it is, but I'd like to kinda extend your question if you will: could chrome extensions access the pressure data (like, with an NPAPI plugin)?

Answer (score 2):

If you use the firefox 4 or later, you can get pressure value from DOM MouseEvent's "mozPressure" property.

Please see also:

1. http://dougturner.wordpress.com/2008/12/10/mouse-pressure-support-in-mozilla/
2. https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/MouseEvent

Answer (score 0):

I believe the stylus, which contains the pressure sensor, is made by Watcom in that unit. They would need to write a custom plugin to offer browser support for their device. Send them a mail!